# Datagridview columns not appearing properly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview and they are not appearing the way they should be in the design. 
Here are the items of the datagridview

1. Activity Textbox databounded
2. Date Textbox databounded
3. Timeline ID Textbox databounded visible false
4. Event ID Textbox databounded visible false
5. delete Button not databound

this the sequence when the program is runned

1. Activity
2. delete
3. Date

. why is the delete button in the middle. i'm sure i placed the button control last in the design.

Comment: Please can you share your code, otherwise we literally have no clue!

Comment: What part of the program sir? i actually don't know cause i did it on design.

Comment: Are the columns autogenerated? if not, is their order still ok in the designer? And does it match the order in the datasource? are the names correct and are the members all named?

Comment: No sir, i added them manually. actually sir the delete in the description is a button i forgot to mention it.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all code adding/inserting columns into the `DataGridView` and the binding of the `DataSource`.

Comment: where can i find it sir? i actually don't know where it is because i added the columns in the design time I create a form called Form1.

Comment: In that case, it would be in `Form1.Designer.cs`.